# Pass session through secure channel without losing it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I have installed nopcommerce v 2.5 on abc.domainName.com and I have a wildcard SSL Certificate to different domain name but on Same server ex abc.domainNameSSL.com. So When I'm using it, When I transfer from non-secure page to secure page, I am losing my session.

So Can anyone tell me What is best way to pass session in this condition.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you crossing application domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are authenticated on one domain and then transfering to another domain, you'll loose the session cookie because it can not cross domains.

For example if you are logged into abc.name.com and then transfer to another domain (i.e. abc.nameSSL.com), even if it is the exact same website you'll loose the session. The server is looking for the session cookie which was stored under abc.name.com. Now that you are on abc.namessl.com it can not find it. Thus you are not logged-in.

A work around would be to not change the root domain (name.com) and instead do something like abcssl.name.com. You'd have to set up a domain wildcard for the session cookie, but it would work.

Comment: thanks for replying.. But suppose I cann't do what you are saying..So Is there any other way for doing it like Passing session through URL or in some hidden form..??

Comment: What is in your session? Is it just the fact that they are logged on, or is there sessionState data involved?

Comment: If you they are just logged on you can preserve that by passing a token via the querystring.

Comment: ya there could be data involved.. Like when a non logged in user add product to cart but cart page is in ssl so it will loss that data..I want to prevent that..

Comment: @Pankaj You could use an out of proc session service. There are two possiblities: Sql Server and In Memory. This would allow you to share session between the applications. Each has it downsides...

Comment: thanks for help..I have done some hack to share same session on both the domain name.